# Rails 3 dynamic time based jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, rubygems, rake

In my Rails 3 application, users are given a small package that they will only be able to hold for a short amount of time e.g 20 mins. The package's ownership is stored in a table with a users `has_many` packages relationship. After 20 mins has elapsed, the package should transfer ownership to another user. This means updating relevant tables and re-adding another time based event as this process is repeated.

Additionally, the start time for each 20 mins interval is random, it is a user initiated process.

Could this be done using any of the common solutions to time based events like cron, delayed_job etc? I expect that this would result in a massive queue of events if there were many packages being passed around.

One extra note - the 20 mins ownership transfer process can also be interrupted. This means that the solution should also take into account that these dynamic jobs can also be cancelled individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.
Both [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) and [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) have built-in scheduler and [resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) has [plugin](https://github.com/bvandenbos/resque-scheduler) for that. It's pretty straight forward with these systems.

Comment: Thanks :) I'll give resque-scheduler a shot!

Answer (score 1):

The whenever gem is great at configuring cron tasks from your Rails app.

https://github.com/javan/whenever